# Angular2 ag-grid-ng2

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

Getting this error while compiling the grid.

Need dynamic component support and using ag-grid-ng2 free version. I am using enterprise license.

> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   node_modules\ag-grid-ng2\lib\ng2ComponentFactory.d.ts:3:10
>       Module '"C:/_Git/ANGULAR/Angular2UI/node_modules/@angular/compiler/index"'
>   has no exported member 'RuntimeCompiler'.

Comment: try upgrading the angular library

Comment: You need more information on versions. Get the latest angular 2 and the latest ag-grid (ag-grid-ng2 was dropped quite a while ago and is not ag-grid-angular on googles request).  The RuntimeCompiler was renamed JitCompiler in version 2.3.0 of angular so your angular 2 base library looks more recent than your ag-grid library.

Comment: Problem is fixed.